Can't upload a json file on google virtual machine
I have no basic knowledge regarding linux commands. I watched some YT tutorials for this. So please give me some rope here.
enter image description here
Upon uploading the necessary json file for my .py file to run, the file is said to be "transferred" but after checking in the intended directory, it can not be found. This .json is named "key_to_gdrive"
xing01086@performaneupdate:~$ cd scripts2/
xing01086@performaneupdate:~/scripts2$ ls -l
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 xing01086 xing01086 4222 Aug 24 02:02 file2.py
-rw------- 1 xing01086 xing01086 4217 Aug 23 18:13 file2.py.save
drwxr-xr-x 6 xing01086 xing01086 4096 Aug 24 02:01 myenv
xing01086@performaneupdate:~/scripts2$ find /home/xing01086/scripts2 -name "key_to_gdrive.json"
xing01086@performaneupdate:~/scripts2$ ype here

enter image description here
Don't know if I'm doing it wrong.
Thank you inadvance.
uploading a .json file onto google VM

Your question is unclear. I assume (!?) you're using the "UPLOAD FILE" button to upload the JSON file. If so, the file is probably uploaded to the user's home directory on the VM. You can list this folder's contents with either ls -la ~ or ls -la ${HOME}. If it's there to move the file to the scripts folder you can mv ~/key_to_gdrive.json ~/scripts and then ls -la ~/scripts.

If this file is a Service Account key, you should rely Application Default Credentials's ability to obtain credentials (through keys) using the Metadata service accessible to Compute Engine VMs instead of copying keys to VMs.
